# What does "to wait out a full school year" mean?

Tags: american-english, terminology

The setting is in modern day U.S. The character, a teenager, and his mother move places a lot. Then they decided **"to wait out a full school year"** in a his mom's friend's house in Portland.

I'm not familiar with the U.S school system, so what does it mean? Does it mean they waited for the school year to be over so he can start from the beginning of the new one?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, except the idea is to *complete* a full school year in one school, and not keep moving from school to school. It says nothing about their intentions for the next school year.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with the school systems in the U.S. It could apply to any place in the world that has schools.

Comment: I'd assume "to wait out a school year" means to not go to school until the next year, but I guess it could mean to wait until the end of the school year while attending classes. M-W says "wait out" means "to await an end to", but to me it usually has a connotation of not doing anything while you're waiting, e.g. to "wait out a storm" means to sit tight until the storm abates. But I definitely don't have an authoritative answer.

Comment: @StuartF, you are right in so far as *wait out* carries an implication of not doing much that is relevant in the context, but it is possible that the context here is one in which doing something relevant would be moving, and that the point is thus that they wouldn't do anything so far as moving is concerned, until the end of the school year. On the other hand, if the context were focused on the teenager's education, then *wait out* could imply that he would be out of school for the time being and then restart his education afresh in the next school year.

Answer (score 1):

"wait out" means to wait until something is over. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wait%20out)

> to await an end to

So in this case, they're waiting until the school year is over before moving again. The implication is that they don't want to interrupt the boy's education by moving in the middle of the school term. It's usually easier to start at a new school at the beginning of the term, since everyone else is also starting fresh.